# Order votes system in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pins

I implemented a simple way to let users upvotes pins, But I would like to order the pins by the number of upvotes, here is my upvote system:

**app/controllers/pins_controller.rb**

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  @pin.votes.create
  redirect_to(pins_path)
end
```

**app/models/vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :pin


end
```

**app/models/pin.rb**

```
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
```

And my **routes.rb** looks like:

```
resources :pins do
  member do
    post 'upvote'
  end
en
```

So I would like my **app/views/pins/index.html.erb**

to show the pins by most upvoted to less upvoted.

I know that [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) provide a system to do that, but as I did not use that gem to implement my vote system, I am not sure it's a good idea to use it.

What do you think?

My **app/views/pins/index.html.erb** is as following:

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <%= image_tag pin.image.url(:medium) %>
      <div class="panel-body">

        <p class="startupinfo">
          <%= pin.startupname %><span class="reward"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <%= pin.reward %></p></span>

        <p class="startupname"><%= pin.description %></p>

        <p class="startuptag"><i class="fa fa-map-marker turquoise"></i> <%= pin.tag %> <i class="fa fa-tags turquoise"></i> <%= pin.city %><%= link_to upvote_pin_path(pin), method: :post do %> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-1x" style="color:#28c3ab"></i>  <% end %>
            <%= pluralize(pin.votes.count, "upvote") %></p>

        <p class="users-edit">
        <%= link_to pin_path(pin), class: "btn btn-success" do %> Tweet <% end %>

        <% if pin.user == current_user %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
          <%= link_to 'Delete', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**BASED ON BALOO ANSWER:**

I ran:

```
rails generate migration add_votescount_to_pins votes_count:integer

rails generate migration add_countercache_to_votes counter_cache:integer
```

I updated manually the migration **_add_votescount_to_pins.rb** so it looks like:

```
class AddVotescountToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :votes_count, :integer
    Pin.reset_column_information
        Pin.includes(:votes).all.each do |pin|
    Pin.update_counters(pin.id, :votes_count => pin.votes.size)
  end
end
```

I ran:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then I added the following line into my **pins.controller.rb** :

```
def index
    @pins = Pin.all
    @pins = Pin.order(votes_count: :desc)
  end
```

Now my **schema.rb** file looks like this:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140704125839) do

  create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "tag"
    t.string   "reward"
    t.string   "startupname"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "tweet"
    t.string   "logo"
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "rewardcode"
    t.string   "logo_file_name"
    t.string   "logo_content_type"
    t.integer  "logo_file_size"
    t.datetime "logo_updated_at"
    t.integer  "votes_count"
  end

  add_index "pins", ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"

  create_table "startups", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "location"
    t.text     "tag"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "pin_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "counter_cache"
  end

end
```

But my pin index still doesn't order by number of upvotes !
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you down vote it destroys?

You can add `votes_count` integer column to pins then add a `counter_cache` to the vote.

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pin, counter_cache: true
end
```

This will increment votes_count on a pin as someone votes for it.

Then simply query based on that

```
@pins = Pin.order(votes_count: :desc)
```

In your migration you'll want to update votes_count based on the existing votes.

```
add_column :pins, :votes_count, :integer, default: true
Pin.reset_column_information
Pin.all.each do |pin|
  Pin.reset_counters(pin.id, :votes)
end
```

Comment: I don't have a down vote system, I want to give the user the possibility to up vote only. I'll try your method and keep you updated. Thanks btw

Comment: I updated my question with what you said - but it's still doesn't ordering, can you check if I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Remove this line `@pins = Pin.all`, also you don't need a `counter_cache` integer column on Pins - because the class name is `Vote` it will look in `Pin` for a column called `votes_count` this is your counter cache column

Comment: I remove this line and replace it by @pins = Pin.order(votes_count: :desc) but it's still doesn't ordering as I want. I updated my pins/index.html.erb in my question - even if i don't think that the error come from this file.

Comment: So I should remove the counter_cache integer from my Pins columns? I updated my question with my schema.rb file - Because I don't have any counter_cache integer column on Pins - as it is on column votes (see schema.rb updated in my question)

Comment: Yep.  Are you sure the votes_count column is correct?

Comment: Should I put a votes_count integer inside the votes column instead of the Pins column ?

Comment: No, it updates the votes_count on the pin.  It should be on the pins column.

Comment: Ok here is the thing: I rand rake db:migrate before updated my _add_votescount_to_pins.rb with the following Pin.reset_column_information
Pin.includes(:votes).all.each do |pin|
  Pin.update_counters(pin.id, :votes_count => pin.votes.size). Could it come from here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56781/discussion-between-baloo-and-zacchj).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it without counter cache you can try this:

```
@pins = Pin.joins(:votes).select('pins.*, COUNT(votes.id) AS vote_count').group('votes.pins_id').order('vote_count DESC')
```

Comment: Where should I implement this? In my pins_controller.rb - inside index?

Comment: Yes, if that's where you want to show the Pins sorted by votes